# login issues with phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

Whenever I write localhost/phpmyadmin on the address bar, I am asked to enter a username and a password,I have tried username as root and password blank it says server http://localhost:80 requires username and password. I have also tried a different password $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] being set to false but the problem is still there. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL server really has a root user without a password, you should set $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] to true in phpMyAdmin's config.inc.php in order to log in with this root user.

Answer (score 0):

When WAMPServer installs the `\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\config.inc.php` is set like this

```
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

So if yours has `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;` then you or someone has been fiddling with it.

Set it back to this default setting and try again.

If you still get a login problem then you probably have another MYSQL Server running on your system. The other MYSQL is probably set to Start Automatically on boot and is therefore running and stopping WAMPServers MYSQL to start. However wampserver see's it and thinks its its own MYSQL.

So if this is the case stop and probably uninstall the other MYSQL, after making sure its not being used for something important, and doing any backups of databases just to be safe.